# Cannot Read property '_id' of undefined while using mongoose findOneandUpdate

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mean.io

I am using mean.io to make sports event management system.I am trying to update a model Player with rest api and it throws this error from mongoose:

```
  { _id: 5411c79895d600440c698fa1,
  email: 'abc@bcd.com',
  name: 'James Bond',
  username: 'james.bond',
  games: [ 5411bd54786cfe2420f1e27a ],
  teams: [],
  roles: [ 'authenticated' ] }

[TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined]

PUT /api/players/5411c79895d600440c698fa1 500 199.402 ms - 36
```

I also tried to delete the _id proterty from player but it doesnot works either.
the method i have used to update the model player is :

```
exports.update = function(req, res) {
    var player = req.player;
    player = _.extend(player, req.body);        
    console.log(player);

    Player.findOneAndUpdate(req.params.playerId, player,{new:true}, function (err, updatedPlayer) {
        console.log(err);
        if (err) {
            return res.status(500).json({
                error: 'Cannot update the player'
            });
        }
        res.json(updatedPlayer);
    });
```

And also if i used the `model.save` method provided in the default package `article` of `mean.io`, it shows another error. I have extended the `user` model in player package `app.js` file. So whenever I try to update one field, the field that I have declared in `app.js` are required and the path required error from mongoose is thrown.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two issues in your update request.

First, the `findOneAndUpdate` expects a dict as the query and not just the id, so you should give it `{_id: req.params.playerId}` instead.

Second, passing a mongoose object as the update data is risky, instead you should convert it to a dict like this `var _player = player.toObject()` and then have `_player` be passed to the update request. Remember that you need to remove the `_id` param of`_player` because you can't change the `_id` of a document. Before doing the update just do `delete _player._id` and you should be fine. Also, `new` is set to `true` by default so you won't need the options dict.

Here is your working code:

```
var player = _.extend(req.player, req.body);        
var _player = player.toObject();
delete _player._id;

var query = {_id: req.params.playerId};
Player.findOneAndUpdate(query, _player, function (err, updatedPlayer) {
    ...
});
```

But in this case you shouldn't even have to do the first operation. Since you just want to update the data of `req.body` you can do:

```
var query = {_id: req.params.playerId};
var data = {
    $set: req.body,
};
Player.findOneAndUpdate(query, data, function (err, updatedPlayer) {
    ...
});
```

This will update all the fields of the player matching the `query` with the values from `req.body`.

Comment: Thanks for the `toObject` mate. Cheers. Been figuring out why I can't query `document.something._id` from queried doc, even though `JSON.stringify(model.something)` shows that there's `_id` field on the `something`.